# Facebook SDK integration with android?

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook

I import the Facebook SDK to the eclipse but it show's me the error on following imports. Ii search everywhere for the libraries of these import but failed to find. Kindly suggest me with some solution to resolve these imports errors. ...

```
android.support.annotation.Nullable;
android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
```

Comment: in which library ? mentioned one are not of Facebook but on Android Support Libary

Comment: https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html Follow the url to setup Android Support Library

Comment: Switch to android studio. Its recommended

Comment: i added the import library many of the errors resolved thanks for suggesting me that but i am still getting error on android.support.annotation.Nullable; suggest me how to find library for android.support.annotation. I did'nt find any library for that Murtaza Khursheed Hussain

Comment: I think it's time to use Android Studio and gradle :)

Comment: i dont want to go on android studio. Is there any solution to solve this problem by stying here in eclipse . @edbaev

Comment: @KhubabHamza so just add the latest android v4 library :)

Comment: sill it shows error. @edbaev

Comment: Make sure you go to the "Modules" tab under app settings, click on your app's top level module, and have "android-support-v4 or v7" listed under the dependencies. That being said, Android Studio and Gradle will make all this a lot easier. Short term pain for long term gain.

Comment: try to clean project :) Actually It's hard to fix your problem. because you use an Eclipse and maybe the problem with versions